# Почему в PyCharm выводит ошибку с ппервой и второой линией, а через Idle всё работает коректно?

Tags: python

```
import random

class Die():
    def __init__(self, numder):
        self.sides = 20 #Количество граней кубика
        self.numder = int(numder)

    def roll_die(self):
        """Моделирует бросок кубика с 6-тью гранями """
        number = 1
        while number <= self.numder:
            one_edge = self.sides
            throw = random.randint(1, one_edge)
            print(throw)
            number += 1

cube = Die(10) #Количество бросов
cube.roll_die()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не работал в PyCharm, но предположу, что у него свое окружение виртуальное. И там нет random модуля

Comment: Что за директория lesons_for_python и что за модуль с именем random.py там лежит? И ошибка у вас именно там.